# Copy paste an image from pdf file while maintaining transparency

Tags: pdf, images, copy-paste, adobe-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to maintain image transparency when copying from the browser](https://superuser.com/questions/237784/how-to-maintain-image-transparency-when-copying-from-the-browser)

I have a pdf document and when I try to copy-paste an image from it with the Selection Tool, the background becomes black.

I found this problem in both Paint.NET and Word 2010, so I am assuming that it comes from the pdf or from adobe reader.

What settings do I need to change in Adobe reader 9 to make the paste background transparent?

Comment: Same issue as the duplicate. Copy-paste clipboard doesn't handle the transparency. Export or save out the image first.

Comment: @random How would you save a single image from a pdf file?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/134869/how-to-extract-image-from-pdf-file

Comment: This question should not be closed. I'm not interested in solutions for browsers.