# Copy paste an image from pdf file while maintaining transparency (open issue)

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10.

Please don't close as duplicate of

[Copy paste an image from pdf file while maintaining transparency](https://superuser.com/questions/361426/copy-paste-an-image-from-pdf-file-while-maintaining-transparency)

**Browsers are different than PDF viewers. I followed the links and none of the other discussions give an easy solution**

If you have a regular version of Adobe Acrobat, say, and no specialized software, is it or is it not possible to extract an image with transparent background kept?

Just copy paste into a word processor or Paint.net makes the background black, not transparent.

Ideally no batch processing or command-line interfaces. Best answer is "install this free program and then regular copy paste works".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying PNG with transparency from browser shows a black background instead](https://superuser.com/questions/237784/copying-png-with-transparency-from-browser-shows-a-black-background-instead)

Comment: That's the EXACT question I am saying the linked question is not a duplicate of! The question I was linking to was closed as a duplicate to your link WHICH IT IS NOT.

Comment: Did you follow the entire link chain? The question that my proposed duplicate links to in fact states that Copy/Paste _does not maintain transparency_. That's not a browser issue, it's not an Acrobat issue, it's an OS (Windows) issue.